# Node.js async parallel TypeError: task is not a function on raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm pretty newbie with nodejs so please don't let the hate flow through you if i'm asking any simple questions.

I'm trying to use nodejs on a raspberry pi 3 to control two motors. I get the async task is not a function error. I was searching for an answer but none of them that i found were working for me. I could use a hand with this.

Below is the code:[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXMfQ.png)

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path'),
async = require("async"),
rpio = require('rpio'),
app = express();

app.set('port', 3000);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/static')));

var http = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Serverul started on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var tank = {
    motors: {
        leftFront: 11,
        leftBack: 12,
        rightFront: 13,
        rightBack: 15
    },
    init: function() {
        rpio.open(this.motors.leftFront, rpio.OUTPUT);
        rpio.open(this.motors.leftBack, rpio.OUTPUT);
        rpio.open(this.motors.rightFront, rpio.OUTPUT);
        rpio.open(this.motors.rightBack, rpio.OUTPUT);
    },
    moveForward: function() {
        async.parallel([
            rpio.write(this.motors.leftFront, rpio.HIGH),
            rpio.write(this.motors.rightFront, rpio.HIGH)
        ]);
    },
    moveBackward: function() {
        async.parallel([
            gpio.write(this.motors.leftBack, 1),
            gpio.write(this.motors.rightBack, 1)
        ]);
    },
    moveLeft: function() {
        gpio.write(this.motors.leftFront, 1);
    },
    moveRight: function() {
        gpio.write(this.motors.rightFront, 1);
    },
    stop: function() {
        async.parallel([
            rpio.write(this.motors.leftFront, rpio.LOW),
            rpio.write(this.motors.leftBack, rpio.LOW),
            rpio.write(this.motors.rightFront, rpio.LOW),
            rpio.write(this.motors.rightBack, rpio.LOW)
        ]);
    }
};

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('move', function(direction) {
        switch(direction) {
            case 'up':
                tank.moveForward();
                break;
            case 'down':
                tank.moveBackward();
                break;
            case 'left':
                tank.moveLeft();
                break;
            case 'right':
                tank.moveRight();
                break;
        }
    });

    socket.on('stop', function(dir) {
        tank.stop();
    });
});

tank.init();
```

Comment: the async.parallel takes as a first param an array of functions. Each function as to return a callback after it's done. Have you checked if rpio.write returns a callback after it's done, a promise or nothing?

Answer (score 0):

`rpio` calls to write and open are all synchronous calls according to the docs.  You don't need to use async at all, but if you do want to do so then you need to wrap the calls in a function that takes a callback, because that's what async is expecting.  Simple example:

```
// wrap your synchronous function
function wrap(fn) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); 
  return function (cb) {
    try{
      var results = fn.apply(null, args);
      cb(null, results);
    } catch(e) {
      cb(e);
    }
  }
}

async.parallel([
  wrap(rpio.write, this.motors.leftFront, rpio.LOW),
  wrap(rpio.write, this.motors.leftBack, rpio.LOW),
  wrap(rpio.write, this.motors.rightFront, rpio.LOW),
  wrap(rpio.write, this.motors.rightBack, rpio.LOW)
 ]);
```

/***  RESPONSE TO COMMENT ***/
In your original code, you use rpio, but then in your comment you said you're using pi-gpio.  The library matters, and the API for the two are very different.  For example, rpio functions are all synchronous while pi-gpio are all asynchronous already.  In the pi-gpio version, you have to provide a callback to all your calls to pi-gpio functions (just like your error tells you to).

The easiest way to modify your existing code would be to make heavy use of function parameter binding.  For example in your moveForward function, you currently have:

```
moveForward: function(){
  async.parallel([
    rpio.write(this.motors.leftFront, rpio.HIGH),
    rpio.write(this.motors.rightFront, rpio.HIGH)

  ]);
}
```

You'd need to bind those first two write arguments to the gpio.write function, which will return a function that takes the last param expected (and in this case, provided), the callback.  gpio.write takes the signature, `gpio.write(pin, highLow, callback)`, so doing this:

```
moveForward: function(){
  async.parallel([
    gpio.write.bind(this.motors.leftFront, rpio.HIGH),
    gpio.write.bind(this.motors.rightFront, rpio.HIGH)

  ]);
}
```

Should have the result you want.  Though [from the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pi-gpio) you still should consider how / when you're closing the pin.

Comment: I modified your code and tried to use it but i still get this error:  `(node:6979) DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback k is deprecated.`. I'm using the pi-gpio module becuase the rpio is not working with raspberry pi model 3 B.